# EntityFramework MVC Create multiple different Entities from one view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor, database-connection

I'm working on an EntityFramework project and running into an interesting problem.  What I want to do is create a database entity using a view, but in order to do that I need to create another database entity of a different type that the first entity needs to be associated with, and I'm trying to do this from the same view.

For example, we have a Person, and each Person will have a recurring appointment.  However, appointments can be recurring on different types of criteria.  Right now I'm trying to get this working on appointments that will be on a daily basis (meaning, for example, every Monday, Wednesday, and Friday)  So here, my model is something like:

DailyAppointment implements the abstract class AppointmentFrequency

Person has an AppointmentFrequency associated with it.  Here is the code behind my model (database generated using code-first migrations).

AppointmentFrequency :

```
public abstract class AppointmentFrequency 
{
    [KeyAttribute]
    public int Identity { get; set; }
}
```

DailyAppointment :

```
public class DailyAppointment : AppointmentFrequency
{
    public bool Monday { get; set; }
    // ... Variable for each day of the week.
}
```

Person:

```
public class Person
{
    [Key]
    public int Identity { get; set; }

    //... Other information

    [ForeignKey("AppointmentFrequency_Identity")]
    public virtual AppointmentFrequency AppointmentFrequency { get; set; }

    public int? AppointmentFrequency_Identity { get; set; }
}
```

So in our view, when we create a Person, we want to have an AppointmentFrequency associated with them.

Currently, my approach involves a partial view inside the view that creates a Person:

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("AddPerson", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post, new { role = "form", @class = "form-inline" }))
{
    ... //This is where we get information about the Person

    Model.Person.AppointmentFrequency = new DailyAppointment();
    var dailyAppointment = Model.Person.AppointmentFrequency as DailyAppointment;
    if (dailyFrequency != null)
    {
        @Html.Partial("_DailyAppointmentEditor", Model.Person.AppointmentFrequency as DailyAppointment);
    }

    <div class="form-group">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Add</button>
    </div>
  }
```

(I have also tried doing this a few similar ways, such as sending the dailyAppointment variable into the partial view instead)

My partial view looks like this:

```
@model Database.Entities.DailyAppointment


        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Monday)
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Monday, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Monday, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })

        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Tuesday)
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Tuesday, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Tuesday, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })

        ... //The rest of the days and script bundling
```

Inside my controller, I am only creating a Person, and was hoping that the Appointment would be created by the Framework, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddPerson(Person person){
        this.db.People.AddOrUpdate(person);
        this.db.SaveChanges();
        return this.View();
    }
```

I know one way of doing this would be to collect the data and then use it in the form post sent to the controller, creating the frequency, and then adding the reference to the person object and creating it in the database.  I have actually done that and know that it works, but I feel like there must be a more friendly way of doing this within the framework.

Part of the challenge here is that I'm hoping to make this extensible while still using the same design.  Let me know if I can give any more information, but if you have any suggestions for this approach or for a different approach I can take, I would greatly appreciate it!  Thank you.

Comment: Have you considered ViewModels? http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/06/30/how-we-do-mvc-view-models/

Comment: Yes I have, although I anticipate a problem when it comes to having different types of Appointment frequencies, as once there is more than one I won't know which to initialize in the ViewModel.  Unless I am misunderstanding what I can do with a ViewModel.

Comment: The reason this wont work is that `AppointmentFrequency` is an abstract class and the `DefaultModelBinder` cant create create an instance of an abstract class and how would it know which concrete type to initiate anyway. [This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781022.aspx) may be useful.